.Net Maui and Facebook App Promotion Issue
I have a .NET MAUI app and I want to promote it on Facebook. I set up a campaign, selected the app from the Play Store, but Facebook says:
Missing or Invalid Field in Promoted Objects: For the optimization goal "App Installs," the "application_id" field needs to be valid. Please set it in the Promoted Objects. (#1815437)
Apparently, to track installs, Facebook requires me to install the Facebook SDK and integrate it with my app. However, there isn't a Facebook SDK package available for .NET MAUI. Unfortunately, you can't advertise without app install tracking.
The only option I see for now is to advertise my application's Facebook page and then somehow manually promote the app from there.
Has anyone else found a solution to this issue?

having the same problem too. is there a way to create the SDK manually ?

You have to make a 3rd party library binding for the platforms you are targeting (android/iOS) and include it in the project.  It's not very well documented in Maui yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/dotnetconf-focus-on-maui/binding-native-libraries-for-dotnet-maui

You may need to create the FACEBOOK App first and then link the marketing campaign to it afterwards. Or you can solve it by adding a shared secret in the app dashboard.
